# last code changes not present in application server

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven, jonas

Under Eclipse (with Maven and GWT), i have 4 projects. 
 
I made modifications in my Java code source.
To put my modifications in the application server (a Jonas server), 
 i made a clean / build automatically of all projects, 
 then a GWT compile of the project who contains the entry point. 
 and finally an export WAR of this project who contains the entry point. 
When i put this WAR on the application server (Jonas), and stop and restart of the server, 
 **my last changes are not present in the server !!!**  
 
However, when i run my GWT application in local (localhost:8080), my last changes are present. 
 
 **Do you have met such a situation ? What can explain it ?** 

 Thanks

Comment: did you try to clear your local browser cache?

Answer (score 0):

If you made modifications to a sub-project, but did not increment the version number, it might be possible that you continue to use an outdated version.

It depends on what you mean by "i made a clean / build automatically of all projects, "

I recommand you update the version number of projects when upgrading, and/or build with -U argument (mvn clean install -U)